# Flutter - PageView animatedToPage will load middle page. How to avoid it?

Tags: flutter

I have a PageView, I want scroll pageView programmatically, so I have two choices:

1. use `animateToPage`
2. use `jumpToPage`

now, I need smooth transition effect, so I have to use first api. But, I have a problem: `animateToPage` will load middle pages which don't need to be shown at this time when I scroll from the first page to the last page.(jumpToPage don't have this problem, but I need animation).

How to avoid it?

Comment: Say you are on `0th` page, and you need to animate to `9th` page, what you can do here is, use `jumpToPage(8)` and after that use `animateToPage(9)`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### We can achieve that by

1. Swap lastPage Widget to next position of current page
2. Animate to next page
3. Jump to real lastPage index
4. Refresh swapped Index to its previous value

---

In this example, I used fixed **PageView children count, which is 8.**

#### Demo

[image: Demo]

#### Comparison

1. **Combine to 8th page Button**

as CopsOnRoad suggested, this button will trigger **Scroll animation** to last page (in this case 8th page). Firstly, we
jumpToPage(6), and then animateToPage(7, ..).

This method works, **but adversely, user will notice sudden change of current page to 7th page**.

2. **Flash Jump to 8th page Button**

Unlike like first method, this button will avoid displaying 7th page unnecessarily

#### Syntax Explanation

**this is the main function**

```dart
void flashToEight() async {
  int pageCurrent = pageController.page.round();
  int pageTarget = 7;
  if (pageCurrent == pageTarget){
    return;
  }
  swapChildren(pageCurrent, pageTarget); // Step # 1
  await quickJump(pageCurrent, pageTarget); // Step # 2 and # 3
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(refreshChildren); // Step # 4
}
```

**detailed look**

```dart
// Step # 1
void swapChildren(int pageCurrent, int pageTarget) {
  List<Widget> newVisiblePageViews = [];
  newVisiblePageViews.addAll(pageViews);

  if (pageTarget > pageCurrent) {
    newVisiblePageViews[pageCurrent + 1] = visiblePageViews[pageTarget];
  } else if (pageTarget < pageCurrent) {
    newVisiblePageViews[pageCurrent - 1] = visiblePageViews[pageTarget];
  }

  setState(() {
    visiblePageViews = newVisiblePageViews;
  });
}

// Step # 2 and # 3
Future quickJump(int pageCurrent, int pageTarget) async {
  int quickJumpTarget;

  if (pageTarget > pageCurrent) {
    quickJumpTarget = pageCurrent + 1;
  } else if (pageTarget < pageCurrent) {
    quickJumpTarget = pageCurrent - 1;
  }
  await pageController.animateToPage(
    quickJumpTarget,
    curve: Curves.easeIn,
    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  );
  pageController.jumpToPage(pageTarget);
}

// Step # 4
List<Widget> createPageContents() {
    return <Widget>[
      PageContent(1),
      PageContent(2),
      PageContent(3),
      PageContent(4),
      PageContent(5),
      PageContent(6),
      PageContent(7),
      PageContent(8),
    ];
  }

void refreshChildren(Duration duration) {
  setState(() {
    visiblePageViews = createPageContents();
  });
}
```

### Full Working-Example Repository

You may look into full source code and build locally. [Github](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_tricky_layout/blob/master/lib/h_screen/jump_page_view.dart)

Comment: Clever solution, and it looks really great, however my number one complaint is that widgets will be rendered multiple times. Which at least for my case isn't ideal, since I'm making a call in the initState()

Comment: Should this be a Flutter feature? We prefer not use ` WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()` to refresh widgets.