# How to make page transition when use bottomNavigationBar in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, platform-specific

I use a basic bottomNavigationBar and now it shows just page without any transition,i want to use page transition when tap different bottomNavigationBars item.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IndexedStack` Widget

```
int _currentIndex = 0;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: _currentIndex,
          children: const [
            HomePage(),
            SettingsPage(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (int index) => setState(() => _currentIndex = index),
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: 'Settings'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: when i tap on homepage to settingsPage then page will be changed when change this page i want a transition and move next page.how to solve this?

Comment: If the above source is executed, the page will be switched when the bottom navigation bar is clicked. When you move to the next page, what page are you moving to?

Answer (score 0):

use PageView or TabView
[Check this article](https://karthikponnam.medium.com/flutter-pageview-withbottomnavigationbar-fb4c87580f6a)

Comment: yap i know,but i need BottomNavigationBar.Have there any solution to you?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
 List pages = [
    HomeScreen(),
    DiscoverScreen(),
    Container(),
    MessageScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(),
  ];
```

```dart
Scaffold(
      body: pages.elementAt(current!),
 bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: widget.current!,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.green,
          showSelectedLabels: true,
          showUnselectedLabels: true,
          onTap: (val) {
            setState(() {
              current = val;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bottom Nav Transition With Persisting Ui**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomNavTransitionWithPersistingUi extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavTransitionWithPersistingUi({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomNavTransitionWithPersistingUi> createState() => _BottomNavTransitionWithPersistingUiState();
}

class _BottomNavTransitionWithPersistingUiState extends State<BottomNavTransitionWithPersistingUi> {
  late PageController _pageController;
  late List<Widget> _tabBody;

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController(
      initialPage: 0,
      keepPage: true, // for ui state
    );
    _tabBody = [
      const NavHomeView(key: PageStorageKey("NavHomeView")),
      const NavMoreView(key: PageStorageKey("NavMoreView")),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBarItems,
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
        children: _tabBody,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get _bottomNavigationBarItems => BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            label: 'More',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
        elevation: 0.1,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        enableFeedback: true,
        onTap: _onNavBarTapped,
      );

  void _onNavBarTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });

    _pageController.animateToPage(
      index,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
    );
  }

  void _onPageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}

class NavHomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavHomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 500,
          color: Colors.purple,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 500,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 500,
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class NavMoreView extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavMoreView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 500,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 500,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 500,
          color: Colors.amber,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: here is some issue that if i have four items in BottomNavigationBar and when i move 1st item to 4 no item directly on that time 3 transition happen together .How to solve this?

Comment: Please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586983/flutter-pageview-animatedtopage-will-load-middle-page-how-to-avoid-it)